# Magento Load Categories in Admin order

Tags: php, magento, plugins

I'm trying to load all of the categories that are marked to be included in the navigation in Magento in the same order as they are in the Admin panel in order build a custom layered menu (we combine the output with another menu stored in the DB to other pages).

This is what I am using in the function to generate the menu so far:

```
private function generateCategories() {

    $_root_category_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite(true)->getDefaultStore()->getRootCategoryId();

    $_current_children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addIsActiveFilter()
        ->addLevelFilter(2)
        ->addOrderField('position', 'asc');

    $i = 0;

    $html = '';

    foreach( $_current_children as $l0 ) {
        if ($l0->getID() != $_root_category_id && $l0->getName() != '' && $l0->getIncludeInMenu())  {

            $i++;

            if (Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() == $l0->getURL())
                $active = ' active';
            else
                $active = '';

            if ($l0->hasChildren())
                $parent = ' parent';
            else
                $parent = '';

            $html .= '<li class=" level0' . $active . $parent . '"><a href="' . $l0->getURL() . '" class="top">' . $l0->getName() . '</a>';

            if ($l0->hasChildren()) {
                $multiplier = 1;
                $iteration = 0;

                $level1 = '';
                $level1[] = '';

                foreach ( explode(',', $l0->getChildren()) as $l1 ) {

                    $l1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($l1);

                    if ( $l1->getIncludeInMenu() ) {

                        if (Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() == $l1->getURL())
                            $active = ' active';
                        else
                            $active = '';

                        if ($iteration == $this->perColumn) {
                            $iteration = 0;
                            $multiplier++;
                        }

                        $iteration++;

                        $level1[] = '<span class="level1' . $active . '"><a href="' . $l1->getURL() . '" title="' . $l1->getName() . '">' . $l1->getName() . '</a></span>';
                    }
                }

                unset($level1[0]);

                $numLinks = count($level1);
                $columns = $numLinks / $this->perColumn;

                $html .= '<div class="border-cover"></div><div class="dropdown" style="width: ' . $this->colWidth * $multiplier . 'em;">';

                $used = 0;
                $iteration = 0;

                foreach( $level1 as $link ) {
                    $used++;
                    $iteration++;

                    if ($used == 1)
                        $html .= '<div class="col" style="float: left; width: ' . $this->colWidth . 'em;">';

                    $html .= $link;

                    if ($used == 4 || $iteration == $numLinks) {
                        $html .= '</div>';
                        $used = 0;
                    }
                }

                $html .= '</div>';
            }

            $html .= '</li>';
        }
    }

    return $html;

}
```

I was under the impression that `->addOrderField('position', 'asc')` should filter the categories into the same order as in the Admin panel, but this only works on the first level (`$l0`) categories, not the sub categories as well.

Can anyone suggest how this could be modified for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the function getChildrenCategories() instead of getChildren this will return an object rather than an id of a category so you would then not need to load the information.

More information can be found at [Change sort order of Magento subcategories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898819/change-sort-order-of-magento-subcategories)

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.  I didn't realise that their was a way to return that categories as objects, I thought they had to be loaded after.

Answer (score 0):

$subcategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $categoryId)
->addAttributeToSort('name', ASC);
?>

Comment: it's not about the name!