# Change default product listing direction for some categories

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I need to change the default product listing direction on some category list pages. As you know there is no such option Magento admin, so I need to do this programmatically.

Categories that needing product sort direction override is a sub-category of another category, let's call that parent category ID 1. 
How can I override category 1's all children categories' default sort order?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898819/change-sort-order-of-magento-subcategories

Comment: @Manashvibirla That question related by categories itself. I need to do this on product listing page, on products. Adding clearification to question.

Comment: product listing page will display the products from same category, how can you change the sort of categories on that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change in function in this location 
 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

If you get Here category then set direction as per your requierement.

```
public function setDefaultDirection($dir)
{
    if (in_array(strtolower($dir), array('asc', 'desc'))) {
        $this->_direction = strtolower($dir);
    }
    return $this;
}
```